# bootstrap popover links does not bubble up

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Popover as follows

On JS and HTML Side I have the following,

```
$('.profileShareBtn').popover({
        html : true,
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'bottom',
        // viewport: { selector: 'body', width: 300 },
        content: function() {
            return $('.socialSharePopupTemplate').html();
        }
    });


<div class="socialSharePopupTemplate">
     <span class="btn btn-default fa fa-times popoverCloseBtn pull-right"></span>
         <div class="social">
            <a class="col-xs-4 link facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
            <a class="col-xs-4 link twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
            <a class="col-xs-4 link google-plus"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a>
          </div>
</div>

<button class="profileShareBtn></button>
```

But when I try to click these links they do now work as links. They just act link normal text. Any thoughts on this please ?

Thanks you

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function(){ //insert your code here });`. Also, your pasted `html` code is missing `"` after `class="profileShareBtn'here'></button>`

Comment: No No,

The problem is popover is inserted to the DOM when something is clicked or hovered.

So when that happens the links are not initialised. This is why I cannot even handle the events on popover content. You know what I mean ?

Comment: This is the problem I have. See the links are not working   http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/893/

Comment: See this and try [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/0v86k5pm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/0v86k5pm/)

```
<button class="profileShareBtn">Click me</button>

<div class="socialSharePopupTemplate" style="display:none">
    <span class="btn btn-default fa fa-times popoverCloseBtn pull-right">X</span>
    <div class="social">
        <a class="col-xs-4 link facebook" href="facebook" target="_blank">facebook</a>
        <a class="col-xs-4 link twitter" href="twitter">twitter</a>
        <a class="col-xs-4 link google-plus" href="http://www.google.com">google+</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.profileShareBtn').popover({ 
        html : true,
        placement:'bottom',
        content: function() {
            return $('.socialSharePopupTemplate').html();
        }
    });

    $( document ).delegate( ".link", "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(href);
    });

});
```

Comment: Woohoo. Thanks buddy. So the trick was to attach the eventlistner to the DOM. Got it working using the on function http://jsfiddle.net/0v86k5pm/4/

Comment: @user3839915 yes, Indeed. You can use `on` `delegate` or `live` for these actions. Thanks! Please vote up

Answer (score 1):

No No,

The problem is popover is inserted to the DOM when something is clicked or hovered.

So when that happens the links are not initialised. This is why I cannot even handle the events on popover content using jquery. You know what I mean ?