# How do you get the pulsating effect using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm sure I have seen this effect in jQuery, but not sure where or how to explain it properly.

If anyone can let me know it would be really awesome.

For example, See the link below. When you click it the answer will get highlighted for 2 - 3 seconds.

[bootstrap popover links does not bubble up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658115/bootstrap-popover-links-does-not-bubble-up/25659026#25659026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery UI's color animation](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) with jQuery's [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), start with a color when the page loads and fade it to white over the course of 1500 milliseconds (1.5 seconds). You cannot animate background color without also including jQuery UI for that aspect.

[Here is a jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/rr6u6rqs/)

CSS

```
body { background: #D38B28; }
```

JS

```
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 1500)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I think I need to go back to school on jQuery

Comment: The answer is missing a little thing. It will just animate to white color. What if i need to just highlight to a color and then come back to original state.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple enough,

Include jquery UI js in your page and then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 highlight("#myelement","orange");
})

function highlight(element,color)
$(element).css("backgroundColor",color).animate({"backgroundColor" : "#fff"},1500,function(){
$(this).css("backgroundColor","");
})
```

Comment: Thanks Patel, I think I need to go back to school on jQuery

Comment: Brian... Its working there in fiddle. Select jquery 1.9.1 as well as jquery UI